# Labeling a layer with the values of stand-alone table (that is associated to the layer with 1-Many relationship)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I wondering how could we labeling a layer with the values of stand-alone table (that is associated to the layer with 1-Many relationship)

For example, I wanted to label the parcels with their owners knowing that the parcel layer is associated with owners table with 1-Many relationship.

What might be the best practice to perform this task?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adapting the code in my Blog called [Creating Labels with Related Table Data](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2015/02/07/creating-labels-with-related-table-data) to your data.  You do not have to concatenate the two fields in your table, but you do need to adapt the code to create a composite key for the dictionary key.  Here is how the code could be adapted for your label (I am only using the English named field names in my example, since I do not use or understand Arabic).  Make sure you change the parser for the Label to Python.  I did not test the code with my own data, but I believe it should work once you supply the Related Table Path for the line that reads relatedFC = r"C:\YourPath\YourRelatedTableName" and change the field names to Arabic for the feature class (any unquoted field name in brackets).

```
# Initialize a global dictionary for a related feature class/table
relateDict = {}
def FindLabel ( [ParcelNumber], [BlockNumber] ):
  # declare the dictionary global so it can be built once and used for all labels
  global relateDict
  # only populate the dictionary if it has no keys
  if len(relateDict) == 0:
    # Provide the path to the relate feature class/table
    relateFC = r"C:\YourPath\YourRelatedTableName"
    # create a field list with the relate fields first (ParcelNumber, BlockNumber), 
    # followed by sort field(s) (OwnerName_Arabic)
    relateFieldsList = ["ParcelNumber", "BlcokNumber", "OwnerName_Arabic"]
    # process a da search cursor to transfer the data to the dictionary
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(relateFC, relateFieldsList) as relateRows:
      for relateRow in relateRows:
        # store the key value in a variable so the relate value 
        # is only read from the row once, improving speed
        relateKey = tuple(relateRow[0], relateRow[1])
        # if the relate key of the current row isn't found 
        # create the key and make it's value a list of a list of field values
        if not relateKey in relateDict:
          # [searchRow[2:]] is a list containing
          # a list of the field values after the key.
          relateDict[relateKey] = [relateRow[2:]]
        else:
          # if the relate key is already in the dictionary 
          # append the next list of field values to the 
          # existing list associated with the key
          relateDict[relateKey].append(relateRow[2:])
    # delete the cursor, and row to make sure all locks release
    del relateRows, relateRow
  # store the current label feature's relate key field value
  # so that it is only read once, improving speed
  labelKey = tuple([ParcelNumber], [BlockNumber])
  # start building a label expression.
  # My label has a bold key value header in a larger font
  expression = '<FNT name="Arial" size="12"><BOL>Parcel {} Block {}</BOL></FNT>'.format(labelKey[0], labelKey[1])
  # determine if the label key is in the dictionary
  if labelKey in relateDict:
    # sort the list of the list of fields
    sortedList = sorted(relateDict[labelKey])
    # add a record count to the label header in bold regular font
    expression += '\n<FNT name="Arial" size="10"><BOL>Owner Count = {}</BOL></FNT>'.format(len(sortedList))
    # process the sorted list
    for fieldValues in sortedList:
       # append related data to the label expression
       # my label shows a list of related
       # owners sorted in alphabetical order
       expression += '\n{}'.format(fieldValues[0])
    # clean up the list variables after completing the for loop
    del sortedList, fieldValues
  else:
    expression += '\n<FNT name="Arial" size="10"><BOL>Owner Count = 0</BOL></FNT>'
  # return the label expression to display
  return expression
```

The Blog provides examples of ways to format your list of owners, especially if you want multiple fields from the owners table laid out in a table like format.  You also will need to change the font from Arial to a font that works for Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

I think ArcGIS will take care of it for you once you've joined the table to the feature layer. 
Here is a tutorial that goes through it in some detail, 
http://grindgis.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-plotting-multiple-values
though i can't vouch for the vba scripting.

The step you  are missing is to have a unique primary/foreign key pair to perform the join. At the moment 'parcel number' and 'block number' form a 'composite' or 'concatenated'  key. To create a unique key you could create a new field in both tables to act as a unique primary key. To populate this new field use field calculator to convert the block number and parcel number to strings and concatenate them. Remember to include a hyphen or similar in between, else 15 and 6 will come out the same as 1 and 56.